# Linq to entity - exclude children based on childs grandchildren

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I need help with a problem I cant get my head around. I want to get a questionnaire with only the questions that arent answered.

To be clear, a person should be able to request a questionnaire, answer one question out of, lets say, a total of 5 questions. And then when one requests the questionnaire the next time, it should be returned but with only 4 of the questions (the unanswered ones).

I tried it with lambda includes also but cant get it to work. Any help is truly appreciated!

The classes are structured like

```
public class Questionnaire()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Question> {get; set;}
}

public class Question()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int QuestionnaireId {get; set;}
    public List<Answer> {get; set;}
}

public class Answer()
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int QuestionId {get; set;}
    public int QuestionnaireId {get; set;}
    public List<ReceivedAnswer> {get; set;}
}

public class ReceivedAnswer()
{
    public int AnswerId {get; set;}
    public int QuestionId {get; set;}
    public int QuestionnaireId {get; set;}
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have tables :

```
Questionnaires[QuestionnairesID, QuestionID]
ReceivedAnswers[PersonID , AnswerID]
Questions[QuestionID,Question]
Answers[AnswerID,QuestionID,Answer]
```

Linq Query would be like:

```
var pp = (from q in questionnaire.Questions
         join a in question.Answers on q.questionid equals a.questionid
         join ra in ReceivedAnswers on ra.answerid equals a.answerid
         where ra.personid == inPersonID
         select q.questionid).ToList();

var output = from questionnaire in _unitOfWork.Questionnaires
        where questionnare.Id == questionnaireId && !pp.contains(q.questionid)
        select questionnaire
```

Comment: Cant join on question since it does not exist in the context.
The only direct access i have is to the Questionnaire.Everything else is children objects. Ill update question to clarify